# The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' no longer has a Release file

Tags: ubuntu, repository, ubuntu-22.04

friends I was trying to update my Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy, at that time I got the error

```
The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/repo.zabbix.com_zabbix-agent2-plugins_1_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease - PrepareFiles (13: Permission denied)
W: chmod 0600 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.zabbix.com_zabbix-agent2-plugins_1_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease failed - Item::QueueURI (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0644 of file /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.zabbix.com_zabbix-agent2-plugins_1_ubuntu_dists_jammy_InRelease failed - 400::URIFailure (30: Read-only file system)
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix-agent2-plugins/1/ubuntu jammy InRelease: Couldn't create temporary file /tmp/apt.conf.6NHbT7 for passing config to apt-key
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_jammy-backports_Release - PrepareFiles (13: Permission denied)
```

The result for my

```
lsb_release -a
```

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Release:        22.04

Codename:       jammy

I tried following some solutions suggested for similar steps, I tried to update the repository.

```
sudo sed -i -e 's|X|$(lsb_release -cs)|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

but ended up getting error
sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/apt/sedomvevn: Read-only file system.
Hope someone could help me resolving this issue.